# How i need pass ID and name into varibales and execute Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I Need to execute 2 Procedures
 Ex :

```
Exec usp_Employee @name = 'Employee'

Exec usp_Department @ID = 2,@name = 'Department'
```

I have a master table where I have records like this

```
ID name
1  Employee
2  Department
3  Class
```

How can I pass this table data into variables send to the Procedure as parameters

The Employee name should go to usp_Employee Procedure as parameter and the ID and Department name should go to usp_Department Procedure as parameter

I have created Execute SQL TASK in that I have placed this Procedures

```
 Exec usp_Employee @name = ?
    Exec usp_Department @ID = ?,@name = ?
```

And used For loop  container but it is not  executing as expected.

How can I loop the master table data into variables and pass it as parameters to those Procedures.

Suggest me

Comment: what do the procedures do? Can you post the source code for those? It looks like you are doing RBAR updates or insertions so yes, you could use a loop here but it wouldn't be ideal

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @scsimon in those procedures I will get employee data and Department data and will load into excel destination

Comment: Fair enough, you lost me at excel.

Comment: @scsimon ok OLEDB Destination or where ever I want I can put that data into that ..why to make me fail with my question if you are not trying to help me

Comment: I'm not trying to make you fail... I just said you lost me at excel. I'm sure some vba and excel guru will server up an anwer.

Comment: [dup](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3ea8e8aa-112a-4260-b554-5f86451f0449/how-i-need-pass-id-and-name-into-varibales-and-execute-procedure?forum=sqlintegrationservices) on MSDN.

Comment: @SMor i'm the same person who asked there..is it not allowed to use multiple knowledge sharing platforms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need an Execute SQL task before your Foreach Loop. In that first Execute SQL, write a query to select the records from your table that you're interested in.

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  Name
FROM SomeTable;
```

On the General tab, set the ResultSet to "Full result set". On the Result Set tab, assign the results to an Object variable.

In your Foreach Loop, loop over the Object variable on the Collection tab. On the Collection tab, set the Enumerator to "Foreach ADO Enumerator". Your object variable should then be available to select in the "ADO object source variable" drop down list. On the Variable Mappings tab, create two new variables, say CurrentInt and CurrentString (probably an INT32 and a String) and assign the Object variable values from the current loop iteration to those variables. Those two variables will be passed to the tasks inside the loop container.

Inside the Foreach container, use an Execute SQL task. On the Parameter Mapping tab, pick up the two variables that the Loop container set.  Add local variables inside the task, assign the passed parameters to those, then use the locals inside the task. So in your example, something like this should do the trick:

```
DECLARE 
  @IdFromTable INT = ?,
  @NameFromTable VARCHAR(50) = ?;

EXEC usp_Employee 
  @name = @NameFromTable;

EXEC usp_Department 
  @ID = @IdFromTable,
  @name = @NameFromTable;
```

Comment: it's good how I need to populate the "?" parameters from variables .How to get the variable data this is where I'm more concerned

Comment: I expanded on my answer.

Comment: I will try from  my side and get back to you

Comment: "In your For each Loop, loop over the Object variable on the Collection tab" what exactly I need to here I'm unable to move on this

Comment: On the Collection tab, set the Enumerator to "Foreach ADO Enumerator". Your object variable should then be available to select in the "ADO object source variable" drop down list. I added this to the answer.

Comment: "Add local variables inside the task, assign the passed parameters to those" I have added local variables while executing it is giving Declare Scalar variable